# What happens to vaporized metal in the atmosphere when it cools down?

Tags: metal

Imagine you vaporize a chunk of metal like an iron meteorite or plutonium or whatever in the atmosphere. What happens to that metal when it cools down? Does it form dust and drop in the nearby vicinity or does it float away in the wind or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Vaporized pieces  of metals may float when cooled in the upper atmosphere for many months. It depends on the dimension of the particles. A good proof of this movement is the famous fallout problem due to the residues of the nuclear tests carried out in the years 1950 - 1964. During these years, USA and USSR were engaged in a course to more power. They developed more and more powerful atomic bombs launched from the Pacific Ocean by USA, and from Kazakhstan by USSR. The last bombs thrown in 1963 were thousand times more powerful than the first bomb in Hiroshima. The residues of these bombs was of course discharged in the upper atmosphere, and dispersed all over the world by the winds. Radioactivity was measured all over the world. And it was steadily increasing in all parts of the world. Then suddenly in 1964, Russians and Americans met in Geneva and they both decided to stop their nuclear tests. They said that it was for promoting peace everywhere. It was a great relief in the world. But the truth is that both Russians and Americans knew that the amount of radioactivity had grown up to 1/10 of the point where all food would have to be decontaminated to be eaten in the whole world, and of course at home. So they stopped nuclear tests. And slowly the radioactivity measured all over the world decreased. There was a small increase when China exploded its own bombs. And now the radioactivity of the soil has been probably washed to the oceans. On the ground, in food and people, it is back again to its level of before World War II. Today, the only measurable radioactivity is due to rare nuclides like K-40 and C-14 which are naturally present everywhere. We are used to them.